# How to query different references in firebase and check if one of the child is equal to the other childs value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I  am not sure if the question seems perfect but I wIll appreciate any help

here is my firebase database

[image]

I have 2 different references.one is the user and the other is the item..its a buying and selling app..I want to set the users image to his item on the show item activity...

how do i go about the query..

if boyo@yahoo.com post an item,I want the other users to see his image and his full names under the showitemactivity

here is a screen showof my show activity item[image]

thanks in anticipation

here is the code I am using

```
private fun getItemDetails(itemId: String?) {
    val firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

    var rootRef: DatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.reference


   rootRef.child("Items").child(itemId!!).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {


            if (p0.exists()) {
                val sellerid: String = p0.child("uid").value.toString()
                (imagesArray as ArrayList<Items>).clear()

                for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                    val items = p0.getValue(Items::class.java)
                   /* var decimalFormat: DecimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#,##0.00")
                    var formattedValue: String = decimalFormat.format(items!!.getpricee())*/
                    (imagesArray as ArrayList<Items>).add(items!!)

                    priceTV!!.text = items.getpricee()
                    titleTV!!.text = items.gettitlee()
                    descriptionTV!!.text = items.getdescriptionn()
                    categoryTV!!.text = items.getcategoryy()
                    subcategoryTV!!.text = items.getsubcategoryy()
                    state!!.text = items.getstatee()
                    lga!!.text = items.getlgaa()
                    date!!.text = items.getdatee()
                    time!!.text = items.gettimee()

                    rootRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                        }

                        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                            if(p0.exists()) {
                                for(snapshot in p0
                                    .children) {
                                    val users = snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
                                    if(snapshot.equals(sellerid)) {
                                        username!!.text = users!!.getFullnamee()
                                        if(users.getImageee().isEmpty()) {
                                            userImage!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatarplaceholder)

                                        } else {
                                            Picasso.get().load(users.getImageee())
                                                .into(userImage)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                            }
                        }
                    })




                }



            }
            sliderPageAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })







}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.  Also please clarify if you're using Realtime Database or Firestore, and the code you're using now that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Okay,I am using firebase realtime database.

Comment: I added the code I AM using that does not work

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  Can you narrow this down to a specific problem you're having?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the users image and attach it to the item ..the screenshot of my showitemactivity says it all..there are 2 references..one is the items and the other is the users..inside the users node ,there is the users image, i need to get that image and put it on his item that he is selling..on the items node there is a child with (uid: "uid" : "ALKWvS03GXW8g4wjiisQrUWGou82").how can i check if that is equal to the users id which is "Users" : {
    "ALKWvS03GXW8g4wjiisQrUWGou82" :

Comment: The question is unclear. You don't need to compare anything if you know that users uid and the url to the image is a child of that node. If you've already loaded the users node from /users, you'll have the image url. If you have the item loaded, you'll know the uid of the user so load that node and then you'll have the url to the image.